# customize camera view size on iphone

Tags: iphone, ios, camera

I want implement camera like Instagram . all photo is Fixed size.
but I can't set `UIImagePickerController` frame with `CGRectMake(0,0,200,200);`

how can I change camera's view size?

how can let all photo fixed size?

it's fullscreen now!

need help.3Q

Answer (score 1):

As UIImagePickerController is a standard iOS controller,I don't think it allow to set frame to make it custom sized.But still you can give a look at cameraOverlayView.There is a very small chance you can do something with dis.

Answer (score 1):

camera like instagram usually be implemented with `AVFoundation`, which is more flexible, and use `AVCaptureSession` with the camera preview layer for the camera preview size